# Which interface recommended to access I²C device

Tags: i2c

I can successfully access a BME680 device through I²C. `i2cdetect 1` shows the device and I found out that two APIs seem to be perfectly usable -- I wonder which one I should prefer.

I `open()` the device, `ioctl()` to the corresponding address and then can use either the most generic  `write()` or the SMBus special `i2c_smbus_write_i2c_block_data()` to write data to the required address. For read the proper combination of `write()`+`read()` works as smoothly as `i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data()`.

Since I am not quite the kernel coder and intend to walk this road only as far as really required, I wonder which approach I should prefer. I could roll a dice -- or make a reasonable decision.

Could anybody point out which is the intended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMBus `i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data()` command just does an I2C write as does your open, ioctl and write.

It really doesn't matter which you use, it's really a matter of personal taste.

Whichever you use I would put a comment in the code saying that the other may be used instead (in case the code is ported to a different environment where only the other works).